# AuthenticateAndContinue Error WP 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, authentication, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to perform authentication in Windows Phone 8.1 using the AuthenticateAndContinue method of WebAuthenticationBroker. This is the page where I perform the authentication.

```
public sealed partial class ScenarioFrame : Page,IWebAuthenticationContinuable
{
    public static ScenarioFrame Current;
    public ScenarioFrame()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Current = this;
        Load();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Invoked when this page is about to be displayed in a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">Event data that describes how this page was reached.
    /// This parameter is typically used to configure the page.</param>
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        Load();
    }
    private void Load()
    {
        WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAndContinue(new Uri("https://manage.windowsazure.com/publishsettings/"),new Uri("https://manage.windowsazure.com/publishsettings/getpublishsettings"));
        Block.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
    public async void ContinueWebAuthentication(Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.WebAuthenticationBrokerContinuationEventArgs args)
    {
        String resp = args.WebAuthenticationResult.ResponseData;
    }
}
```

I have used the ContinuationManager and SuspensionManager available on MSDN in order to use the AndContinueMethod. The app navigates to the ScenarioFrame page when the user clicks on a button in the MainPage. The problem is that WebAuthenticationResult after the callback gives an error in the WebAuthenticationStatus property(UserCancel) and the response is null. This problem doesn't arise in a Windows 8.1 App where I use AuthenticateAsync method. Can anyone clarify how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAndContinue(new Uri("https://manage.windowsazure.com/publishsettings/"), new Uri("https://manage.windowsazure.com/publishsettings/getpublishsettings"),   null, WebAuthenticationOptions.None);
```

Try this